# How to write my normal sql query to laravel 5.2 format

Tags: php, mysqli, laravel-5

I am creating report page in laravel. for creating report i need to fetch data from two table. am fetching data according to four parameter. AccountID, deviceID, fromDate, ToDate. I written the sql normal query. But i don't know how it write in laravel  format.
My sql query for the report creation is

```
SELECT a.accountID, a.deviceID, b.description, a.timestamp, a.latitude, 
    a.longitude, a.speedKPH as speed, a.heading, a.altitude, a.address, 
    a.distanceKM as distance, a.odometerKM as odometer, a.IbatVolts, 
    a.EbatVolts, a.ITempr, a.fuelLevel, a.inputState, a.IgnRuntime, 
    a.GPSFixType, a.GPSPDOP, a.AlertType, a.speedLimitKPH, a.isTollRoad 
  FROM eventdata as a, device as b 
  WHERE a.deviceID='$deviceID' 
    AND a.accountID='$accountID' 
    AND a.timestamp >= $dt1 
    AND a.timestamp<=$dt2 
    AND a.deviceID=b.deviceID 
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

eventdata and device are the two tables.

Can anyone help to write this code in laravel?
responses are appreciable.

Comment: did you created the Laravel relationship between related tables ?

Comment: Actually am new in laravel. And don't know what all are the things need to do, for join two table.

Comment: Please search Laravel Relationships first... then you will understand it

Comment: It would be much better that if you follow the documentation 1st.. dont Jump on solution directly without reading the documentation. 
Follow this link

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: like told you, when you ask questions you should show us what have you tried? why it's not working for you? did you know about eloquent? if not why you not reading the docs?

Comment: @Amir Bar, i have done some fetching things in laravel, from the single table. So i thought for join table the things are same , only the thing i need to know how to write the query in laravel. Thats why i asked and gave the sql query of what i want to do.

Comment: @Qazy, i have done the Laravel relationship between related tables. now can you help me out to write my query in laravel?